# How I get 2 values ​in one line on ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to get two value in one line without split function. Help me to solving this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example? I’m not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign 2 variables in one line you can do

```rb
def multiple_values
  return 1, 2
end

x, y = multiple_values

# x = 1
# y = 2
```

Comment: or just `x, y = 1, 2` – you don’t need a method

Comment: I saw this answer after 2 years later. Thanks a lot !